# How to access local sqlite database of android application from .NET application

Tags: c#, android, web-services, sqlite, synchronization

I want to synchronize android app database with central sql server database.
I currently working on .NET web services,Web service should update remote android database after every 10 minutes.I am not getting exact way.how to do this? I have developed web service but getting error of unable to open database while accessing remote database.
Is it possible to update remote sqlite database from .NET webservices?
please help me.Is there any other solution?

Comment: Have you tried using `System.Data.SQLite`? You have to specifically install it in later versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes sir I have tried it.... I am using connection string as follows: Data Source="\\10.6.70.39 7081\Data\Data\Com.Adani_Hmi\Databases\HMIDB.db;Version=3;New=false;Compress=True" is there any problem with conn string?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the parameter `Legacy Format=True` to your connection string.

Take a look at https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite/ under "Using the pre 3.3x database format."